# Copying Column Ranges within a for loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I am running the following code which works fine, but I cannot find any solutions to simplify it. Have tried to rearrange the syntax in many different ways to shorten the code to two lines but they don't seem to work, can anyone advise on how to simplify this code:

```
'export results to columns
Worksheets(analysis_sheet & " Analysis").Columns(9).Copy Columns(9 + (5 * (i - 6)))
Worksheets(analysis_sheet & " Analysis").Columns(10).Copy Columns(10 + (5 * (i - 6)))
Worksheets(analysis_sheet & " Analysis").Columns(11).Copy Columns(11 + (5 * (i - 6)))
Worksheets(analysis_sheet & " Analysis").Columns(12).Copy Columns(12 + (5 * (i - 6)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `i` when you execute this? Probably a Loop and a with will resume it. Anyways, why do you want to simplify the code if it works? 4 lines is not that much

Comment: This is a very common and very easily solved problem. I suggest you look into loops in VBA and how to use variables rather than hard coding column numbers.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns this is a small snippet of my code, was planning on applying the solution quite extensively. The solution provided by Siddharth bellow manages to simplify the code from 4 lines down to 1, and extrapolating this across my code tidies things up nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...different ways to shorten the code to two lines...

Here is a 1 liner which will copy from `Worksheets(analysis_sheet & " Analysis")` to `ActiveSheet`

```
Worksheets(analysis_sheet & " Analysis").Columns("I:L").Copy Columns(9 + (5 * (i - 6)))
```

If you are copying to the same sheet then change the above code to

```
Worksheets(analysis_sheet & " Analysis").Columns("I:L").Copy _
Worksheets(analysis_sheet & " Analysis").Columns(9 + (5 * (i - 6)))
```

**EDIT**

> That won't work because the OP is copying from columns 9 to 12 – freeflow 16 mins ago

> No. In the term Columns(9/10/11/12 +(5*(i-6))) how does excel know how to update the 9 to 10,11,12 – freeflow 11 mins ago

Let's say the value of `i` is `10` so `9 + (5 * (i - 6)) = 29`. Agreed? So `Col I (9)` will be pasted in `Col AC (29)`. Similarly `Col J (10)` will be posted in `Col AD (30)` as `10 + (5 * (10 - 6)) = 30` and so on...

These two pieces of the code will so the same thing

```
Sub SampleA()
    Dim i As Long
    
    i = 10
    Sheet1.Columns(9).Copy Columns(9 + (5 * (i - 6)))
    Sheet1.Columns(10).Copy Columns(10 + (5 * (i - 6)))
    Sheet1.Columns(11).Copy Columns(11 + (5 * (i - 6)))
    Sheet1.Columns(12).Copy Columns(12 + (5 * (i - 6)))
End Sub

Sub SampleB()
    Dim i As Long
    
    i = 10

    Sheet1.Columns("I:L").Copy Sheet1.Columns(9 + (5 * (i - 6)))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That won't work because the OP is copying from columns 9 to 12

Comment: `That won't work because the OP is copying from columns 9 to 12 – freeflow ` @freeflow And `Col 9 -12` is `Columns("I:L")` :)

Comment: No.  In the term Columns(9/10/11/12 +(5*(i-6))) how does excel know how to update the 9 to 10,11,12

Comment: @freeflow: I think you are confused. See the updated post, Feel free to test it :)

Comment: One last time before I give up.  Look at the OP code.  In your code you have written Sheet1.Columns(9 + (5 * (i - 6))).  What happened to Sheet1.Columns(**10** + (5 * (i - 6))), Sheet1.Columns(**11** + (5 * (i - 6))) and Sheet1.Columns(**12** + (5 * (i - 6)))

Comment: `One last time before I give up. Look at the OP code. In your code you have written Sheet1.Columns(9 + (5 * (i - 6))). What happened to Sheet1.Columns(10**+ (5 * (i - 6))), Sheet1.Columns(**11 + (5 * (i - 6))) and Sheet1.Columns(12 + (5 * (i - 6))) – freeflow` @freeflow Even I will give up after this :) I am not copying individual columns. But a contiguous range to another range. :) Did you test the code? `Sheet1.Columns("I:L").Copy Sheet1.Columns(9 + (5 * (i - 6)))` is the same as `Sheet1.Columns("I:L").Copy Sheet1.Columns("AC:AF")` **OR** `Sheet1.Columns("I:L").Copy Sheet1.Columns(29)`

Comment: IN your examples you keep referring to the 'i' variable.  I'm not.  I'm looking at the hard coded number directly after the columns(.  In the OP code it increments with each line.  In your code it does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225028/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-freeflow).

Comment: @SiddharthRout 's code worked exactly as needed, he accounted for the additional columns within Columns("I:L") as he mentioned,

Comment: @SiddathRout's code might be giving you the answer you are looking for but its not the answer to the problem you posed. For example, in your columns clauses you use 9,10,11,12.  If however these values were 9,13,23,51 would your original code(using these values) produce the same answer as the code presented in the answer.  I think not.

Comment: @tboo132 glad to be of help:)

Comment: @freeflow posting from phone so please ignore typos. The answer that I posted is for this specific problem which like I mentioned is for contigous ranges and not non contigous ranges as you mention :) if it was non contigous ranges, my answer would have been different...

Comment: @freeflow if you are still not satisfied with my solution,  feel free to downvote :)

Comment: @freeflow my ranges were contiguous so in this example it works fine, but interesting to consider if they weren't contiguous and perhaps I should have specifically started that they would be contiguous, but good and informative debate otherwise :)